# Limited Resolution on Intel Core i Series Motherboards

Tags: motherboard

As far as I know, Intel Core i series integrated graphic cards support up to 2560 x 1600 resolution. I'm in the market for a new motherboard, but it looks like most of Intel Core i3 motherboards only support resolution up to 1920 x 1080, except for those with display port.

Is this a limitation of the Core i series or motherboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the limitation of the motherboard. Even the older generations does support 2560x1600. the limitation is built by the motherboard manufacturers.

Ref: http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/graphics/2010/01/25/intel-gma-hd-graphics-performance/1

Consider google "H55 DVI-D" if you want to search for boards supporting it.