# What happens when monitor supports 2560 x 1080 resolution, but computer only supports 1920x1080?

Tags: display, resolution, hdmi, external-display

What happens when a monitor supports 2560 x 1080 resolution, but the computer only supports 1920x1080?

Do you get banding along the left and right edges?

Or does everything get stretched and interpolated?  (If the image gets stretched, is it still crisp enough to render text clearly, or does it get fuzzy as compared to text on a native 1920x1080 resolution monitor?)

Assume the signal will be transmitted via an HDMI cable.

Comment: Why would your PC only support 1920x1080?

Comment: @Seth Good question.  It's not *my* PC, but I think this QA answers your question: https://superuser.com/questions/305640/limited-resolution-on-intel-core-i-series-motherboards

Comment: Ah, didn't think about those.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your display. Usually you have options available to either upscale (more often than not default) or display just a 1920x1080 picture which would mean you get a border all around the screen.

As for the "crispness" of the upscale it (again) depends on your display. Some are better and some are worse at it. You'd have to check reviews for it. Also the physical size would matter, as the pixels of the display would occupy a larger physical space. Up to a point this can be mitigated by a greater viewing distance.

This about your 50" TV that most likely only uses 1920x1080 but as you're sitting several meters away from it the image doesn't really feel blurry. If you walk up to it you will "clearly" start to see pixels and it will feel more blurry.

Comment: The monitor is 29", and will be used at typical reading distance.

Comment: Having a specific model would be more helpful. Depending on it you could check e.g. [Prad](http://www.prad.de/en/index.html) for a review. As it's pretty subjective for the person it's always a good idea to try it out.

Comment: The most probable monitor is the LG 29UM67P.

Comment: This is some odd wording. Maybe update the question with additional information and your actual question or start a new question?